# Golang build tags on multiple lines with go version 1.14

Tags: go, build

I am using multiple Golang build tags in a test suite.

Is there a way to split them into multiple lines in go 1.14?

For instance I want to split this line into multiple lines:

```
// +build integration integration_auth_pwd integration_auth_tls integration_config integration_groups integration_groups_mongodb integration_groups_sql integration_groups_cassandra
```

I have tried to split them like this:

```
// +build integration integration_auth_pwd integration_auth_tls \
//integration_config integration_groups integration_groups_mongodb \
//integration_groups_sql integration_groups_cassandra
```

This didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can't break `// +build` constraints.

You may specify multiple `// +build` lines. But know that space separated constraints in a line are ANDed together, and constraints specified in multiple lines are ORed together, so it's not the same.

You can't break your requirement into multiple lines, use a single line.

A friendly note: Go 1.14 isn't supported anymore. Please do use the latest Go. Whatever security vulnerabilities are discovered in Go 1.14, you'll be vulnerable to those for the rest of your life.

Comment: Many thanks for the quick reply!
Unfortunately we use go version 1.14.
Is there a way to do this in go version 1.14?